# Audio (AVAudioPlayer) stops video loop (MPMoviePlayerController) on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, audio, video, iphone-4

I develop an application for physical exercises which plays audio and video. Since audio and video come from separate files (audio is language dependent, video not), I play the audio with AVAudioPlayer and the video (which does not have a sound track) with MPMoviePlayerController. The video must run in a loop (moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne).

Usually the audio (verbal explanation of an exercise) is started first, some seconds later the video is started (exercise is shown). This works like a charm on iPhone 4S (and of course, in the simulator), the audio plays and in parallel the video loops until it is stopped.

On an iPhone 4 (and on an iPad 1), however, the video does **not** enter the loop, i.e. is stopped after the first run, if the audio player is still playing when the video is started. (If the video is started **after** the audio stopped playing, the loop works fine also on the iPhone 4).

How can I make the MPMoviePlayerController perform the loop also on iPhone 4?

Comment: Did you try playing around with the AudioSession setup of your app?

Comment: I started out without, i.e. with the implicit AudioSession, then I used the explicit one.  It did not change anything.    
    `audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error: &error];
    if (error) {
        DLog(@"Error setting audio session category: %@", )
    }`

Comment: Also I do not see much to play around with, except for the category.

Comment: Yes, the category would be worth a shot.

Comment: I experimented with various categories to no avail. Also playing a bit with Audio Session Properties did not help.

Comment: I think you're going to need to use AVPlayerLayer. MPMoviePlayerController is probably just too inflexible for what you're trying to do.